# Why are these two queries having such different executions?

Tags: mysql, performance, execution-plan, query-performance

I'm trying to get all users that haven't been sent a message in a given day. I have two tables, one with the messages that have a reporterid indexed column, and a reporter table.

Let me walk you through it:

This inner query returns reporters that have received messages in a given day. It takes tenths of a second on my local dev machine:

```
select  m.reporterid
    from  nubamessage m
    where  m.messagetypeenum =7
      and  m.createdOn>='2016-06-18 00:00:00'
      and  m.createdOn<='2016-06-18 09:30:00';
```

There is no difference in the execution time of the above query if I do select(distinct) or not, and it returns the same rows.

But if I used that in an outer join query, it basically never completes:

```
select  *
    from  reporter r
    left outer join  
    (
        SELECT  m.reporterid
            from  nubamessage m
            where  m.messagetypeenum =7
              and  m.createdOn>='2016-06-18 00:00:00'
              and  m.createdOn<='2016-06-18 09:30:00'
    ) as mm  ON mm.reporterid=r.id
    where  r.enabled=1 and m.reporterid is null;
```

However, if I change the inner query to distinct as the below, it takes a fraction of a second:

```
select  *
    from  reporter r
    left outer join  
    (
        SELECT  distinct(m.reporterid)   -- the only difference
            from  nubamessage m
            where  m.messagetypeenum =7
              and  m.createdOn>='2016-06-18 00:00:00'
              and  m.createdOn<='2016-06-18 09:30:00'
    ) as mm  ON mm.reporterid=r.id
    where  r.enabled=1 and m.reporterid is null;
```

The execution plan for the non-completing query:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  r   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11538   50.00   "Using where"
1   SIMPLE  m   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    968388  100.00  "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
```

The execution plan for the query where I just add "distinct", it adds some auto-key:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY r   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11538   50.00   "Using where"
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  NULL    ref <auto_key0> <auto_key0> 5   r.id    10  100.00  "Using index"
2   DERIVED m   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    968388  1.11    "Using where; Using temporary"
```

If someone could find it in their heart to explain to me why 1. the first query never completes/is so slow and 2. why the distinct makes it run fast, even though the inner query returns the exact same rows in both cases, I'd be most grateful.

Thanks

Edit: Notice that I write "all users that haven't been sent a message. This is why I have the left join - later in the query I have "where m.reporterid is null", in order to only get out the reporters that don't already have a message in the messagetable. I have edited the questions above to reflect that.

I could have used a "not in" instead but from what I've read and in my tests it was a bit slower than left join.

Comment: edited the sql queries

Answer (score 1):

`LEFT` is killing performance; remove it unless you have a good reason for keeping it.  To elaborate...

((**but first...** The purpose for the `LEFT` was missing from the original query; this answer assumes the `LEFT` was not necessary.))

`LEFT JOIN` says that you want data from the *right* table, whether or not there was a match with the left table.

`JOIN` says to display only the rows that match (via `ON`) both tables.

(`OUTER` is optional and adds no semantics.)

If you are running a version before 5.6, the derived table (subquery in `LEFT JOIN`) will have no index, so it must be scanned repeatedly.  This is a big reason to get rid of `LEFT`.

Without the `LEFT`, the Optimizer is likely to evaluate the subquery *once*, then efficiently `JOIN` to `reporter` to finish the query.

For `JOIN`, the inner query needs this composite (and covering) index `INDEX(messagetypeenum, createdOn, reporterid)`.

There is another technique (I think)...  Get rid of the inner `SELECT`, simply `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`) to the table:

```
select  r.*
    from  reporter r
    left join  nubamessage m  ON m.reporterid = r.id
      AND  m.messagetypeenum = 7
      and  m.createdOn >= '2016-06-18 00:00:00'
      and  m.createdOn <= '2016-06-18 09:30:00'
    WHERE  r.enabled = 1
      AND  m.reporterid is null;
```

In this case, it *may* needs `INDEX(reporterid, messagetypeenum, createdOn)`.

Yet another variant would use `EXISTS` **and, I think, provides the equivalent of the `LEFT`**

```
select  r.*
    from  reporter r
    WHERE  r.enabled=1
      AND NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT  *
            from  nubamessage m
            where  m.messagetypeenum =7
              and  m.createdOn>='2016-06-18 00:00:00'
              and  m.createdOn<='2016-06-18 09:30:00'
              AND  m.reporterid=r.id 
    )
```

I can't predict which variant will be fastest.  It partially depends on how "many" in the many:1 mapping of `m.reporterid` : `r.id`.

Comment: The thing is that I want the reporters that are NOT in the messagetable. I notice now that I didn't post the entire question, later on I have a "where m.reporterid is null." I only want the reporters I haven't already sent to. This is why I have the left join. I've added some text to clarify.

Comment: My two suggested reformulations may still work for you.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - thanks.  Matthias - I changed both queries.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases `LEFT JOIN` is the first point for optimizations.

This query does the same things as yours, but it use aggregations instead of `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT counters.id
FROM
(
    SELECT r.id, 0 as cnt, 1 as enabl
    FROM reporter r
    WHERE r.enabled=1
    UNION
    SELECT
        m.reporterid as id,
        count(1) as cnt,
        0 as enabl
    FROM nubamessage m
    WHERE m.messagetypeenum =7
        and m.createdOn>='2016-06-18 00:00:00'
        and m.createdOn<='2016-06-18 09:30:00'
    GROUP BY m.reporterid
) AS counters
GROUP BY counters.id
HAVING sum(counters.cnt)=0
    and sum(counters.enabl)>0
```